# Magento VS TYPO3 multishop

Tags: magento, e-commerce, typo3

I'm actually looking for a great eCommerce platform ..

I need to start a project, my employer recommended me Magento, but i can suggest something else.

I really dont know Magento, and im well skilled with TYPO3, so i wonder if im better to use TYPO3 MultiShop or Magento ?

Note : That website will be very big so we need a limitless extensible platform.

What you recommend me for my purposes ? Magento or TYPO3 MultiShop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is the better shop system, Typo3 is the better CMS system.
Since the shop is probably your focus since you want to sell something, I would vote for Magento.

Another option, though, is to combine the best of both worlds by using Magento together with Typo3, for example with this: http://www.typogento.com/

Comment: I really would recommend using Magento if you need a shopping cart. All the way around it's going to be a better shopping cart experience plus you'll get tons of support online since there's a lot of people talking about it as opposed to MultiShop which has a very limited user base.

I it was just static pages I would definitely recommend TYPO3 but not in your case.